# Different definitions of the font \mathscr

Tags: fonts

Looking around, I have found two different "definitions" for the font generated by the command `\mathscr` (aka "Ralph Smith’s Formal Script" according to [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-scriptfonts)).

**First**

[image]

from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mathscr-vs-mathcal.png).

**Second**

[image]

from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/script-r-symbol).

***Questions:***

Why are there two different fonts that supposedly come from the same command?

My LaTeX environment gives me the first font. How do I get the second?

Comment: you have them switched around, by the way

Comment: Here is an image of all available open type math fonts and their math script fonts http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226673/59716

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command `\mathscr` and similiar ones don’t refer to a specific font. If you look at different math fonts like Cambria Math, Asana Math, XITS, Minion Math etc. you see that they are designed with different ideas in mind, hence they look different.

Typing `\mathscr` just request symbols that look script-like. Of course every font designer has had a different idea what “script-like” should be for his font, thus you get different results. This means that there is no precise definition what `\mathscr` should look like. Some fonts may not have such symbols at all, some may have more than one, like XITS where you can get a “calligraphic” and a “script” like looking variant of the font.

The actual symbols you get depend on what math font is loaded  via `\setmathfont` in case of `unicode-math` and LuaTeX or the more traditional NFSS in case of PDFTeX. With NFSS setting the math fonts is more involved. So usually this is done by loading an appropriate package via `\usepackage` that switches to the fonts in question.

Answer (score 7):

Different packages define `\mathscr` in different ways.

The first font is defined in the `mathrsfs` package (I've seen it in many other places as well).

The second font is actually part of the [XITS Math font](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math). You can get it by using the code in the answer you linked. You will have to download the font and install it on your system. You will also need to compile your document using `xelatex` or `lualatex`.