# How to type sheaf hom

Tags: fonts

I want to type sheaf hom into LaTeX how can I do it? In Hartsthorne it appears as something like `$\mathscr{H}om$` but I don't think this is right. For example, because the space between the 'H' and 'o' is too big. What can I do?

Comment: you might want to add a picture of what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise people have to look up you keywords first.

Comment: Ravi Vakil uses a nice-looking sheaf hom in [*The Rising Sea*](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) (paragraph 2.3.C of the November 18, 2017 draft linked here). The source code doesn't seem to be publicly available, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newcommand*{\sheafhom}{\mathrm{H}\kern -.5pt om}
```

Comment: Although, note, the H is in Hartshorne a mathscript letter, so one should use `\mathscr{H}` and one of the [many fine `mathscr` packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43133/different-definitions-of-the-font-mathscr)

Comment: @AlexNelson, do you think that `\mathcal` could do the the job?

Answer (score 8):

An ugly hack, but it looks pretty good:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calligra,mathrsfs}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{\mathscr{H}\text{\kern -3pt {\calligra\large om}}\,}

\begin{document}
$\Hom(X,Y)$
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: sheaf-hom]

Answer (score 0):

This version uses the `BOONDOX-calo` script font. I barely notice the misaligned connecting strokes at my typical reading size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{BOONDOX-calo}
\DeclareMathOperator{\SheafHom}{\mathcal{H\kern -3pt o\kern -2pt m\kern -1pt}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}
the sheaf $\SheafHom(A, B)$ and the set $\Hom(A, B)$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output image]