# Handwritten Letters for Category Theory?

Tags: shorthands

I'm studying category theory and I'd like to know which package I should use to get a handwritten style like this:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Does `\mathscr{T}` give what you want?

Comment: It seems not to work with small letters..

Comment: You can try the `boondox` or the `dutchcal` packages.

Comment: That is a matter of the font you are using. It has to have the small letters for the Script font, you can use e.g. XITS Math

Comment: Interesting.. I'll verify this aspect, thanks..

Comment: which engine are you using?

Answer (score 5):

If you use one of the unicode engines, `xelatex` or `lualatex`, which also have true type font support, you can choose your own math fonts.
However, the number of available, fully functional mathfonts is countable with two hands.

You can even specify own fonts for the different math=alphabets. You need to load `fontspec` and `unicode-math`. You can then define the fonts with `\setmathfont{<font>}` for the global Math font or you can specify a font for certain ranges like this: `\setmathfont[range={<\mathfoncommands,...>}]{<font>}`

Here a little example with mathfonts that are included in TeX Live:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
  \mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{gather*}

\paragraph{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr}]{XITS Math}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
  \mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{gather*}

\paragraph{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr}]{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
  \mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{gather*}

\paragraph{Tex Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr}]{Tex Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{gather*}
  \mathscr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \\
  \mathscr{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]