# What's the symbol for the curly D used to denote a dissection for a Riemann integral?

Tags: symbols

In an analysis lecture today the lecturer used the following curly D symbol to denote a dissection (for a Riemann integral):

[image: curly D symbol]

How can I get this symbol with LaTeX? I've tried to find it in the comprehensive symbol list, as well as with Detexify, but haven't succeeded.

Comment: Is `\mathcal{D}` enough? Load `amsfonts`.

Comment: [Have you tried Detexify](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YpbiX.png)? [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is listed in [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: @Werner, according to OP, he did.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226673/59716

Comment: `\mathscr{D}` from `mathrsfs` package might be an option

Comment: checking on google for "riemann integral dissection", it appears that there are two different opinions about this.  some authors use an ordinary "D" (italic because it's math), and some use a calligraphic form `\mathcal{D}`.  under the circumstances, this seems to be more suited to a math forum than to tex.sx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *collection* of three possible symbols, just propositions

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

% Copied from mathrsfs.sty
\DeclareSymbolFont{rsfs}{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathscrsfs}{rsfs}

\begin{document}

\huge

$\mathcal{D}$


% Euscript
$\mathscr{D}$


% Ralph Smith's font (mathrsfs.sty)
$\mathscrsfs{D}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i've no complaint about either of these suggestions, but see my comment on the question regarding what shows up in published references as found through a google search.  notation is often a slippery, subjective creature.  it may take a practitioner in the particular field to give an authoritative answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Your comment appeared after my answer, the later just being a suggestion