# Fake bold in LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, bold, emphasis

I am sometimes using a font that has no boldface, so I am wondering whether or not there is a way to use some `fakebold`-feature in LuaLaTeX.

The `fontspec` documentation explains a feature for XeLaTeX, which does not (yet?) work in LuaLaTeX.

1. Does `fakebold` already work in LuaLaTeX?
2. If not, is something like it planned?
3. If yes, is there any scheduled release date for this feature?
4. If no to all the above: is there a hack or workaround?

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[20pt, a4paper, DIV=calc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[AutoFakeBold=2.0]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

A Test. \textbf{A bold test}?

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you have any problem to try it out?

Comment: I did and it does not work. I added a MWE to my question.

Comment: Times already _has_ a bold variant.

Comment: Yes. This, however, is a MWE for testing and showing. I did not want to spent time on looking for a font that (a) does not have a boldface  **and** (b) is installed on every user's system. A MWE should work on all systems.

Comment: It can be implemented in `luaotfload`, but XeTeX implementation has its [problems](http://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/61/) already, so a better solution is needed first (not that I volunteer to implement it).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

@ 1,
yes it does work in LuaTeX. Here's how. Note that this also works in plain pdfLaTeX if you throw out lines 2 and 3.

```
\documentclass[20pt, a4paper, DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{%
    \pdfliteral direct {2 Tr 1.5 w} %the second factor is the boldness 
     #1%
    \pdfliteral direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}

\begin{document}
A Test. \textbf{A »bold« test}?
\end{document}
```

@ 2, via fontspec, it doesn't work in LuaTeX yet, but you know that already :)

@ 3, see Khaled's comment

@ 4, yes, I guess what I justed posted can be considered a workaround or even a hack, as it bypasses fontspec and works at pdf level

*that said,* I strongly disadvise against using either this hack (with Lua) or `fakebold` (with Xe) as a substitute for a proper bold font, as the results are unpredictable -- when it comes to printing!

I tried using `fakebold` not to fake bold, but to create a fake footnote-size grade of a font that, like most fonts in our times, only comes in one grade. A grade optimized for a smaller size usually has (among other features) its stroke width increased, particularly in the hairlines and serifs. This is what I wanted to emulate. What I did was add just a tiny little bit of extra fake-boldness in `\footnotesize`, so the serifs at that size were as sturdy as the ones at `\normalsize` (rather than proportionally thinner).

[image: fake opticals]
*fake opticals using a fake boldness of 0.16. Note how, at different point sizes, serif thickness remains identical (or different, depending on how you look at it)*

While, after some tweaking, things looked great on screen, particularly when magnified, what ended up on paper was horrible. The `\footnotesize` passages, on a contemporary business-class LaserJet at 1200dpi, were way too fat. Reducing the amount a bit yielded no significant change. Reducing it further, I abruptly arrived back at the font's default appearance. This probably has to do with the way the printer interprets the original font outlines vs. how it interprets the font outlines with added fake boldness.

Note to self: just like fake italics, fake bold is not an option for serious typographic business. But, to be fair, noone promised it would be :)

Comment: Is there a more parsimonious `fontspec` way to do this? for example, something similar to `ItalicFeatures=FakeSlant`

Comment: If I wanted to do fake-bold for just one font (i.e. not redefine \textbf), how could that be done?

Comment: Tryed and stil does not work for lualatex beta 0.80...Does FakeBold feature works for lualatex current version now? maybe i have old version?

Comment: works like it should on my system (updated today). Lua beta 0.80.0. Fontspec 2.4e. Try running a complete update (`tlmgr update --all` or the like)...

Comment: There is an extra space right before the `%`: `{2 Tr 1.5 w} %the second`. Please remove it, it shows up in the output.

Comment: Outdated. Does not compile with Lua. Just use the `FakeBold` option of `fontspec`. See this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444657/262813.