# Italics in the title in Beamer Metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, presentations, themes, beamer-metropolis

I am using `metropolis` theme in `beamer` but I want to italicize particular words in the title.
What I have below doesn't produce the right result. `{\protect\textit{special italicized words}}` doesn't make a difference. **Edit:** ideally, I would want the italicized text to remind boldface.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}


\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{bg=red} 
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\usepackage{pifont}



\title{Title \emph{special italicized words}}

\date{}
\author{Author Author}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\textnormal`:

```
\title{Title \textnormal{\emph{special italicized words}}}
```

[image]

Regarding bold italics: the font uses OT1 encoding for some reason. In this encoding the font does not have bold+italic shapes. You can switch to T1 encoding using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

An alternative is to use PDF specials to fake bold for italic text (see [Fake bold in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102578/fake-bold-in-lualatex), also for pdflatex). This does not need T1 encoding. The MWE below shows both options.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{bg=red} 
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\fakebold}[1]{%
    \pdfliteral direct {2 Tr 0.5 w}%the second factor is the boldness 
     #1%
    \pdfliteral direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}

\title{Title \textnormal{\fakebold{\emph{special italicized words}}}}
% alternative:
% \title{Title \textnormal{\textbf{\emph{special italicized words}}}}

\date{}
\author{\textbf{\textit{Author Author}}}
\institute{Institute}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ideally, I'd also want the text to remain boldface (while italicized). But `\textbf` won't work here.

Comment: @bozidarka see edit.

Comment: One could write `\title{Title \itshape special italicized words}` instead of `\title{Title \textnormal{\fakebold{\emph{special italicized words}}}}`.

Comment: @Mico in OT1 encoding `\itshape` does not work for bold in this font, there fakebold is a solution. Using T1 you can indeed use `\itshape` or `\textit` as I used in the author line below.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend compiling your Beamer presentations in LuaLaTeX and adding the line

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

or

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

That loads the modern fonts in the same format you use on your desktop, and cuts the Gordian knot of a lot of technical debt to the ’80s.  The one compelling reason to keep using 8-bit font encodings, that some publishers still require you to, does not apply to a Beamer presentation.