# How to use Nils L's "fake bold" for section, subsection, subsubsection, and paragraph headers?

Tags: formatting, bold, section-titles

I would like to (globally) set all section (subsection, subsubsection, and paragraph) headers to be `\medbold` as defined by

```
\newcommand{\medbold}[1]{%
\pdfliteral direct {2 Tr 0.3 w} 
\pdfliteral direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}
```

(Full credit for above code goes to user [Nils L](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7993/nils-l) with their [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102706/268642) to this [StackExchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102578/268642).)

For example, I would like the section header to look like

```
\medbold{[SectionNumber]} [Default Spacing] \medbold{SectionTitle}
```

How do I do this? Thank you very much in advance. Minimum working example is found below

#### Minimum Working Example

```
% Made on Overleaf with the pdfLaTeX compiler
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref} % to give proper credit for the \medbold code
\usepackage{mathtools} %for \mathclap

%Definition of "\medbold"
%Full credit to this code goes to StackExchange Nils L (see href below for more details)
\newcommand{\medbold}[1]{%
    \pdfliteral direct {2 Tr 0.3 w} %the second factor is the boldness
      #1%
    \pdfliteral direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
}

\usepackage[default,
            semibold]{sourceserifpro} %I like this font :)


\title{Medbold Section StackExchange MWE}
\author{cluelessmathematician}
\date{February 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{My Question}

I would like to (globally) set all section (subsection, subsubsection, and paragraph) headers be $\setminus$\texttt{medbold} as defined by

\begin{verbatim}
            \newcommand{\medbold}[1]{%
            \pdfliteral direct {2 Tr 0.3 w} 
            \pdfliteral direct {0 Tr 0 w}%
             }
\end{verbatim}
(Full credit for above code goes to user \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7993/nils-l}{Nils L} with their \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102706/268642}{answer} to this \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102578/268642}{StackExchange question}.)\\


\noindent For example, I would like the above section header to look like
\begin{center}
    \medbold{1} \ \ \medbold{My Question}
\end{center}
\noindent How do I do this? Thank you very much in advance.

\subsection{Dummy Subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Dummy Subsubsection}
\lipsum[2]
\paragraph{Dummy Paragraph}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by `Nils L` works either in `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, hope you expect to work in `PDFLaTeX`, if yes, below `MWE` will works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[bold=0.35]{xfakebold}
\begin{document}

\titleformat*{\section}{\setBold}

\section{A Head Test}
\unsetBold

This is for test

\end{document}
```

Also, note that probably this will work in all `TeX` engines

[image]

I will check the possibility to fix the `\unsetBold` by auto little later.