# Companion for \ell

Tags: symbols

In mathematical writing I often use `\ell` when I need an 'ell' variable, because `l` looks like a `1`. In fact, I expect this is why the symbol exists :).

Now, it often happens that my `\ell` stands for (l)eft, and I would like to have a symbol for an 'r' variable that stands for (r)ight.

> Is there a simple way to make a cursive looking r?

Comment: the easiest way would be to find a script font with lowercase letters and a slope compatible with the slope of the `\ell`.  such an alphabet is present in the stix fonts, and i'm sure someone else can identify a few others.  unfortunately, most "traditional" script alphabets are too heavily sloped, and the most "common" script alphabets designed for use with tex have only uppercase letters.

Comment: I'm surprized there is no link to [that blog post](http://sgowtham.com/journal/producing-script-r-in-latex-expressions/) nor [to that post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21274) in this thread.

Comment: See @sylvain's answer here: [Script-r Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/script-r-symbol?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "Mathematical Script Small R" is just a Unicode character, so if you can enter it in your editor, and you have a font that includes a suitable representation, then it's as simple as this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{STIXGeneral}
\begin{document}
small r:   there.
\end{document}
```

I'm using MacVim and xelatex with TexLive 2013 here and I get this

[image: small curly r]

On the Mac you can get the symbol from the character viewer.  This is the information it gives about it.

```
MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL R
Unicode: U+1D4C7 (U+D835 U+DCC7), UTF-8: F0 9D 93 87
```

And if entering the character from the viewer is too laborious you can always define a little macro for it:

```
\def\arr{\hbox{}}
```

(This feels vaguely like something for http://www.talklikeapirate.com/)

Comment: If it is intended for use in maths one shouldn't use `\hbox` around it but load `amsmath` and put it inside of `\text` to get correct scaling etc.

Comment: @skillmon, can you put your answer up with a minimum working example?

Comment: How do you call your \def?  Can you provide a minimum working exampe?

Comment: @MichaelLevy better would be `\usepackage{amsmath}\newcommand*\arr{\text{}}` and then you could use it with `$d = \pi\arr$` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The `unicode-math` package provides this as either `\mathscr{r}` or `\mscrr`.  Thruston’s solution of pasting  will also work.  Any complete math font should contain it.

By default, `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` are the same alphabet, so you might want to load a different alphabet from the default as your `\mathscr`.  XITS Math and STIX Two Math, for example, provide one as a stylistic set.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\setmainfont{XITS}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={scr, bfscr}, StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\(\mathscr{r} \mathcal{r}\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Script and calligraphic r]

Comment: Package: unicode-math 2018/02/02 vv0.8l Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
! unicode-math error: "not-pdftex"
!
! Cannot be run with pdfLaTeX!
! Use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead.
!
! See the unicode-math documentation for further information.
!
...| LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.
|
| Try typing <return> to proceed.
| If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
|...............................................
)
! Undefined control sequence.

Comment: Please advise on why I have received this error. Please speak plainly.

Comment: @MichaelLevy You’re using PDFTeX. This code only works in `lualatex` or `xelatex`.