# Is there a font/package in LaTeX could generate a lowercase l like this?

Tags: symbols

Is there a font/package in `LaTeX` could generate a lowercase `l` like this (without the arrow)?

[image]

Comment: @campa thanks for your reminder. without the arrow.

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130545/companion-for-ell

Comment: Also, check out http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/frcursive?lang=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$\ell$`. This is defined in the core LaTeX

Comment: Very true.  But the answer would be more useful if it referred him to sources, as well, such as the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, or especially Detexify.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, I've got to ask, are you the same Don Hosek that used to run ymir.claremont.edu ?

Comment: Yes, that's me.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52807598#52807598  :-)