# make math symbol italic

Tags: math-mode, symbols, italic

I must admit that I don't really know my way around LaTeX, pretty much at all. Anyway, here's my problem:

I want to include the symbols `\flat` and `\sharp` in my text. Unfortunately I only receive errors when I put them in like that. So I declared this somewhere

```
\newcommand{\vb}{\ensuremath{\flat}}
```

and it works quite well. Unfortunately I need my text with this symbol always in italics. So when I write `B\vb` (in italics) the `B` and the flat sign will intersect.

Is there any way I can force the flat sign to be italicised?

Comment: Do you write `\textit{B\vb}`? In that case, a little kerning might help, for example `\textit{B\kern0.04em\vb}` or `\newcommand{\itkern}{\kern0.04em}` and `\textit{B\itkern\vb}`. Adjust the `\kern`ing value according to your needs.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies. I exchanged the math mode for $...$ now. And adjusting kerning for these two symbols works to prevent the intersection, so that's nice. But it does look a bit odd to have the first Letter in italics and then the straight symbol afterwards. So while my big problem is solved I still wonder: Is there any way I can force the \flat (or \sharp) sign to be italicised?

Comment: You would need to have a font that contains an italic flat/sharp symbol (I don't know if there are any). You could also try and fake-slant the symbol (probably not the best idea).

Comment: How could I try that?

Answer (score 6):

The italic flat isn't prepared in the fonts. But if you really need it and you are using pdfTeX with direct output to PDF then you can try this:

```
\def\flatit{\setbox0=\hbox{$\flat$}%
   \pdfliteral{q 1 0 .3 1 0 0 cm}\rlap{$\flat$}\pdfliteral{Q}\kern\wd0 }

{\it B\flatit C}
```

[image: sharp]

If you are not using pdfTeX with direct PDF output but you create PDF via `(x)dvipdfm(x)` (XeTeX chooses this way) then you can add the following definition:

```
\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to use this for other symbols/fonts, then note that italic font usually have an angle of 10-12 degrees, which is a shearing factor of 0.18 to 0.21. A factor of 0.3 is 16.7 degrees which is will probably be too much for most symbols in most fonts (the shearing factor is just tan of the incline angle).

Answer (score 2):

The symbols don't clash if you use the proper input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{\itshape B$\flat$ B$\sharp$}

\textit{B}$\flat$ \textit{B}$\sharp$

$B\flat$ $B\sharp$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *really* need the flat in an italic context, precede it with `\/`:

```
{\itshape B\/$\flat$}
```

Of course you can define your personal command like you did.

Comment: And an italic flat would make no sense.