Define custom symbols with boldface
I have defined a symbol \rcurs. I also have its boldfaced form, call it \brcurs. Now, how do I define it such that when I use \mathbf{\brcurs}, it will use \brcurs?
This is from the script $r$ used in Griffith's E&M textbook. The definition is given on his website. In this file, we have the definition of of \rcurs and \brcurs, but it would be great if the latter can be defined as the boldface of the former.
Edit: How \rcurs and \brcurs are defined is actually not relevant. The same question applies to making \mathbf{\alpha} display as \beta.

please provide code for a minimal document showing how you have defined \rcurs and how \brcurs is currently defined. questions should not depend on external links in order to remain useful for future readers. please also tell us which engine you are using.

Note that this is not a duplicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438275/cursive-bold-hat-r-from-griffiths-davids-book as this question here is about how to automatically change \rcurs to \brcurs inside of \mathbf, not about how to define \rcurs and \brcurs.

You should always show a small but complete example that people can use to test solutions.

@UlrikeFischer @cfr How \rcurs and \brcurs are defined is actually not relevant. The same question applies to making \mathbf{\alpha} display as \beta. Providing a minimal example for this particular "script r" is not that easy because in Griffiths' website, this symbol is defined as a imported figure.

than provide a minimal example for alpha/beta. by the way, you can only ping one person per comment, so you notified Ulrike but not me.

I will not answer such a question if I have to write the test code myself. As long as you do not provide an MWE I'm out.

You don't want to use \mathbf.
Define a semantic command for vectors (you can even decide to reuse \vec for the purpose).
With the renewed definitions for \rcurs and friends I gave in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728997/4427
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\genericrcurs}[1]{%
  \text{%
    \resizebox{!}{1.1\fontcharht\font`x}{%
      \includegraphics[trim=20 0 140 0]{#1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\rcurs}{}{\mathord{\genericrcurs{ScriptR}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\brcurs}{}{\mathord{\genericrcurs{BoldR}}}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\hrcurs}{}{\hat{\brcurs}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_single:nTF {#1}
   { \frankwang_vec:n {#1} }
   { \DONTUSEMULTIPLELETTERS }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\vrs}{m}{\hat{\vec{#1}}}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \frankwang_vec:n
 {
  \token_if_cs:NTF #1
   {
    \frankwang_vec_cs:N #1
   }
   {
    \mathbf{#1}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \frankwang_vec_cs:N
 {
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 \rcurs { \brcurs } { \bm{#1} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{center}% let's show the bounding box
\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{$\rcurs$} $\fbox{x}$

% the characters in context
$x\rcurs\vec{\rcurs}$

% they also scale regularly
$\scriptstyle x\rcurs\vec{\rcurs}\vrs{\rcurs}$
\end{center}

\[
  V(\vec{r})=
  \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}
  \int_{\mathcal{V}} \frac{\vec{\alpha}(\vec{\rcurs}')\cdot\vrs{\rcurs}}{\rcurs^2}\,d\tau'
\]

\end{document}

The formulas are nonsensical, they just illustrate usage.


I suppose that your question should be: "how do I define it such that when I use \mathbf{\rcurs}, it will use \brcurs?" It means \mathbf{\rcurs} because there is no sense to do somethig special with \mathbf{\brcurs}.
The answer is: use \let in the argument of \mathbf, i.e. \protected\def\mathbf#1{\mathbfori{\let\rcurs=\brcurs #1}}.
In your example:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newbox\rcursbox  \newbox\brcursbox
\setbox\rcursbox=\hbox{$\resizebox{.16in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{ScriptR}}$}
\setbox\brcursbox=\hbox{$\resizebox{.16in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{BoldR}}$}

\protected\def\rcurs{{\copy\rcursbox}}
\protected\def\brcurs{{\copy\brcursbox}}
\protected\def\hrcurs{{\mbox{$\hat \brcurs$}}}

\let\mathbfori=\mathbf
\protected\def\mathbf#1{\mathbfori{\let\rcurs=\brcurs #1}}

\begin{document}

How about using the macro: \brcurs.

How about using the macro: \rcurs?

Normal and bold: $ab\rcurs, \mathbf{ab\rcurs}, ab\rcurs$

\begin{equation}
{\bf E} = {1\over 4\pi\epsilon_0}\int {\rho\over \rcurs^2}{\hrcurs}\,d\tau.
\end{equation}

\end{document}


Of course, everybody knows that \bf in LaTeX has been deprecated for 30 years.
