# Math Symbols for 'r'

Tags: fonts

In a book on Classical Electrodynamics we meet fonts for *r* and  ***r*** as shown in the image below

[image]

Do there exist these math symbols in LaTeX ?

Comment: This is in Griffiths' textbook right?

Comment: @Vincent : Precisely.

Comment: `calligra` has an `r` that looks rather similar. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\begin{document}
\textcalligra{r}
\end{document}`. I do not recommend using this in formulae, though.

Comment: These are the script lowercase r and bold script lowercase r from the commercial font MathTime Pro 2. See [`mtp2lite` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mtp2lite/texmf/doc/fonts/mtpro2/guide2.pdf) page 35. In particular, the lowercase letters in the square brackets.

Comment: If you purchased the complete MathTime Pro 2 font, then you can access these by calling `\usepackage[mtpscr]{mtpro2}\usepackage{bm}...$\mathscr{r}$ and $\bm{\mathscr{r}}$`. For example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8e4n.png (the terminal stroke is slightly different, possibly from MathTime Pro 1?)

Comment: @Frobenius Very kind my sincere welcome to TeX.SE. Here there are different options: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/script-r-symbol. I prefer the answer of the user sylvain.The `r` is between `Kaufmann-Bold` symbols (`.otf`).

Comment: @Sebastiano : Many thanks. IMO, sylvain's answer therein  is the same as Vincent's herein.

Comment: @Frobenius Excuse me very much. I have not seen the link of Vincent. I used to use that `r` some time ago. Not anymore. In one or more questions asked on this site refer to the `r `you were looking for.

Comment: @Henri Menke : Many thanks for your comment. At the end I found all answers complicated and I do not intend to use such a symbol in any case. Professor Griffiths had created it successfully for special use in his textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of the said book in which this *r* is used, David J. Griffiths, provides some files on his [website](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/griffiths/) to insert it as an image from a `.pdf` file, with an example of use.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in the modern toolchain by loading any script font of your choice as `\mathscr` (as well as `\mathcal`, `\mathbfscr`, etc.)

In this case, I used a font called Parisienne.  You might prefer a different one, but it will do for this example.  (It looks too much like a dotless *i* to me and needs a little more space between r and c.) Existing script fonts were not intended for physics equations.  Since it comes in only one weight, I used `FakeBold` for `\mathbfscr`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Solely to format a MWE on TeX.SX.
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
% Uses the Parisienne font from:
% https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/parisienne
\setmathfont[range=scr]{parisienne-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont[range=bfscr, FakeBold=1.2]{parisienne-regular.ttf}

\newcommand\epsilonnought{\mupepsilon_0}
\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\symbfup{#1}}
\newcommand\upc{\symup{c}}

\begin{document}
Calligraphic \(\symcal{r}\) and \(\symbfcal{r}\) versus
script \(\symscr{r}\) and \(\symbfscr{r}\).

\[ \nabla V = \frac{q \upc}{4 \muppi \epsilonnought}
              \frac{-1}{(\symscr{r} \upc -
                 \symbfscr{r} \cdot \vectorsym{v})^2}
              \nabla(\symscr{r} \upc -
                 \symbfscr{r} \cdot \vectorsym{v})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer but I think it's a little complicated to use since I'm not an advanced user.