# Name of the Vector symbol found in electrostatics

Tags: symbols, vector, pst-electricfield

today I came across a vector symbol in electrostatics denoting the position vector of a test charge with respect to a source charge. The symbol is attached. I searched for the same on the internet but could not find it. Can you please help me with that?[image]

Comment: Looks like [this script r](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/script-r-symbol) with `\hat`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! This symbol appears in the ubiquitous electromagnetic theory textbook by Griffiths. This question may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21274/218142.