# Compiling custom fonts with vptovf

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use the script r symbol in my latex document shown below.

[image]

I found a solution here: [Script-r Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/script-r-symbol) which should do exactly what I'm trying to do, down to the book I found the symbol in. I would like to use accepted solution to that question, but when I run the `vptovf` command in terminal, it just reads out

```
This is VPtoVF, Version 1.6 (MiKTeX 21.6)
Usage: vptovf VPLFILE VFFILE TFMFILE
```

and does nothing. I cannot find another instance of this online or elsewhere.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and MiKTeX 21.6.
Can someone help me get the `vptovf` command to work?

Comment: miktex typically expects three arguments, so you should really give three file names.

Comment: Thank you, but that does the same thing on my system

Comment: did you add the file extension? so `vftovf file.vpl file.vf file.tfm`?

Comment: I did do it that way

Comment: well I just tried in my miktex (after saving the text as griffm.vpl) `vptovf griffm.vpl griffm.vf griffm.tfm` and it worked fine. But I'm on windows, if it doesn't work for you make a bug report.

Comment: It seems we've found a bug then. Thank you