# Using virtual font files in .sty package

Tags: fonts, packages, package-writing, tds

I'm using virtual fonts to generate a "script-r" symbol, exactly following the accepted answer of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21274/script-r-symbol). I am assembling together a .sty file containing code I frequently use, and would like to include these fonts in the .sty file. I have the file in the local folder `~/texmf/tex/latex/`, with all the `griffm` and `griffb` files (`.tfm`, `.vf`, and `.vpl`) included in the folder containing the `.sty` file. The `.sty` file includes the following line (copied and pasted from the linked post):

```
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{griff}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{griff}{m}{n}{<-> s*[2.2] griffm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{griff}{b}{n}{<-> s*[2.2] griffb}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{griff}{U}{griff}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{griff}{bold}{U}{griff}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rcurs}{\mathalpha}{griff}{"72}
\DeclareBoldMathCommand{\brcurs}{\rcurs}
\newcommand*\hrcurs{\hat{\brcurs}}
```

However, if I try to compile using this package, I get the error that the fonts aren't loadable:

```
Font U/griff/m/n/12=griffm at 26.39996pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.                          Font U/griff/m/n/8=griffm at 17.59998pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
Font U/griff/m/n/6=griffm at 13.19998pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
Font U/griff/b/n/12=griffb at 26.39996pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
Font U/griff/b/n/8=griffb at 17.59998pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
Font U/griff/b/n/6=griffb at 13.19998pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

If I move the `griffm` and `griffb` font files to the same folder as the `.tex` file that I'm compiling, these errors go away. So it seems like the virtual font files are being searched for locally, rather than in the folder of the `.sty` file. Is there any way to make it so that the virtual fonts are loaded from the same folder as the `.sty` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the tex distribution will default to assuming that `~/texmf` is in the standard "TDS" (TeX Directory Structure) layout. So your LaTeX package and any fd files which are TeX input should be under `~/texmf/tex/latex` but the fonts should be under `~/texmf/fonts/vf` and  `~/texmf/fonts/tfm`